# Github released successfully but staging repository does not exist, why?

Tags: maven, sonatype

I am using Maven to release net.imadz.Lifecycle 0.9.4 into maven central. I have successfully released 4 versions, but this time I as still confused.

```
mvn clean deploy
```

And then

```
mvn release:clean
```

And then

```
mvn release:prepare
```

And then

```
mvn release:perform
```

And everything was successfully executed. 0.9.5-SNAPSHOT had been created, and 0.9.4 had been pushed into github.com as tagged release at:

```
  https://github.com/zhongdj/Lifecycle/tags
```

And I saw all the 0.9.4 artifacts had been successfully uploaded into remote staging server.

At the moment I suppose staging repository should be automatically created, and I can see it from the following url:

```
https://oss.sonatype.org/#stagingRepositories
```

But after 3 hours, I still cannot find it. What did I miss?

Comment: Please file an issue for this at https://issues.sonatype.org in the "Community Support - Open Source Project Repository Hosting" project.

Comment: Yeah, `Manager of Support for Sonatype` pretty much sums it up...

Comment: This is still not an answer. It's "go somewhere else and ask us to fix it."

Comment: not an issue, I did something stupid. I forget to use mvn clean deploy, but used mvn clean install. So it is my bad, sorry. I was kept having networking issue, which confused me a lot, made my mind so blur. Sorry.

Comment: @BarryZhong I would suggest to remove/delete this question.